# Is it possible to open browser in different machine that you have installed UFT/QTP?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, uft

I want to execute a test in different window machine that I have installed the UFT/QTP software. Is it possible?

I read some information about execute UFT in remote machine(run UFT software and execute the test) but I haven't find any information to open the browser in different machine that I have installed the UFT/QTP software.

Comment: Given the UFT/QTP licensing model, I suspect you'll find the answer is "no". I don't know this for sure - I'll leave that to those with experience with the UFT/QTP software.

Comment: Is SSH login out of the question for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, I use UFT 14.51 version with a license and  I want to run/execute UFT in one machine(1) and open the browser/execute the test in other(machine2). Is it possible?